# Why is my interactive plotly scatter plot running so slowly?

Tags: r, plotly

I've created a plotly scatterplot; however, the interactive plot is currently working at ~1 FPS. I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to speed this up?

```
plot_total <-
  demo %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  ggplot(aes(log2(baseMean), log2FoldChange, color=padj < 0.01,
             text = paste(" log2(baseMean):", formatC(log2(baseMean), format = "e", digits = 2), "\n",
                          "log2FoldChange:", formatC(log2FoldChange, format = "e", digits = 2), "\n",
                          "Gene Name:", Gene, "\n",
                          "ENSG:", ENSG))) +
  geom_point(demo = . %>% filter(!padj<0.01), cex = 0.1, position=position_jitter(w=0.01,h=0.1), size=1) +
  geom_point(demo = . %>% filter(is.na(padj)), cex = 0.1, position=position_jitter(w=0.01,h=0.1), size=1) +
  geom_point(demo = . %>% filter(padj<0.01), cex = 1) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("FALSE" = "#30B7BC", "TRUE" = "#DE653A", "NA" = "#B3B3B3")) +
  labs(title = "Treated vs. Control", x = "log2Expression") +
  theme_bw() +
  NULL

ggplotly(plot_total, tooltip = "text", type = 'scattergl')
```

I have tried changing the `type = 'scattergl'` and `type = 'scatter'` to increase performance, but this doesn't seem to change anything.

Is there a way to reduce the amount of points on the plot? I.e. only show points for `padj<0.01`.

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to add `%>% toWebGL()` and take advantage of hardware acceleration.

`ggplotly(plot_total, tooltip = "text", type = 'scattergl') %>% toWebGL()`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).